# What is the best way to detect console script is runing?

Tags: php, symfony, cron, command

I try to made the console command in Symfony2:

```
class UpdateCommentsCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('comments:update')
            ->setDescription('Update comments');
            ->addArgument('force', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'force', false)
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {

        if (!$input->getArgument('force') && if $flag_this_script_is_active) {
            return;
        }
        $flag_this_script_is_active = True

        $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        // Bad comments
        $update_commang = $em->createQuery("
            UPDATE MyBundle:CommentsAll AS c
            SET
                c.is_automoderated =    1
            WHERE
                bla_bla_bla LIMIT 100
        ");
        $result = $update_commang->getResult();
        if ($result > 0) {
                //Re-run this script with --force argument
        } else {
                $flag_this_script_is_active = false
        }

    }
}
```

This script will run every 60 seconds by crone and proceed untill all commnets will be changed to is_automoderated = 1

If prev script is not over, next script sees that and is not running.

Now I want to know how to set flag `$flag_this_script_is_active`. I want to create some file, and delete it after script is over. But maybe there is a better way. Maybe some symfony functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash script for that purpose. Use `ps aux | grep 'comments:update'` to find already running command and run it if none was found. We used such approach on previous project to detect if daemons are executing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want to use cross-platform solution. It is desirable that it is native to the framework.